# How to set custom margins for a UITableViewCell's .selectedBackgroundView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a table view to display a tree structure. Each cell corresponds to a node that the user can expand or collapse. The level of each node is visualized by having increasingly large indents at the leading edge of the cells. Those indents are set by using *layoutMargins*. This seems to work well for the cell's label and separators. Here's some code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cellLevel = cellLevelForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, CGFloat(cellLevel) * 20.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    cell.separatorInset = insets
    cell.layoutMargins = insets
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId") as? UITableViewCell
    if  cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    cell!.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let cellLevel = cellLevelForIndexPath(indexPath)
    if let textlabel = cell!.textLabel {
        textlabel.text = "Cell @ level \(cellLevel)"
        textlabel.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    cell!.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    cell!.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

    return cell!
}
```

The resulting table looks like this:

[image: Not what I want :(]

The question I'm facing now is this: how can I elegantly apply the same indent to the cell's .selectedBackgroundView, so that it appears flush with the text and separator line? The end result should look something like this:

[image: What I want :)]

Note: I'm currently achieving the desired effect by making the .selectedBackgroundView more complex and adding background-colored subviews of varying size that effectively mask parts of the cell, e.g. like this:

```
let maskView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGFloat(cellLevel) * 20.0, cell!.bounds.height))
maskView.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
cell!.selectedBackgroundView.addSubview(maskView)
```

But I strongly feel that there must be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: This is also the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to make it work. The trick for me was to stop thinking about the *.selectedBackgroundView* as the visible highlight itself (and thus trying to mask or resize it) and to treat it more like a canvas instead.

Here's what I ended up doing. First a more convenient way to get the appropriate inset for each level:

```
let tableLevelBaseInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0)

private func cellIndentForLevel(cellLevel: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return CGFloat(cellLevel) * tableLevelBaseInset.left
}
```

And then in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath*:

```
cell!.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
cell!.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

let highlight = UIView(frame: CGRectOffset(cell!.bounds, cellIndentForLevel(cellLevel), 0.0)) 
highlight.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
cell!.selectedBackgroundView.addSubview(highlight)
```

Seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var selectedView = UIView()    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
                super.awakeFromNib()
        
                
                self.selectedBackgroundView = {
                    let view = UIView()
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    selectedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    selectedView.backgroundColor = .hetro_systemGray6
                    selectedView.roundAllCorners(radius: 8)
                    view.addSubview(selectedView)
                    selectedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
                    selectedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
                    selectedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
                    selectedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
                    return view
                }()
 }
    
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
            
            if selected {
                selectedBackgroundView?.isHidden = false
            } else {
                selectedBackgroundView?.isHidden = true
            }
        }
```